# How to restrict apache2 forward proxy to a list of client IP's?

Tags: debian, apache2

I am new to apache2, so please excuse any elementary mistakes. I am
trying to create a Apache Forward Proxy on a Debian 8.4 Jessie server
for accessing servers outside the organization. The contents of the
file sites-available/000-default.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyRequests On
    Proxyvia On
    <Proxy "*">
        Require ip <my-wlan-ip-here>
    </Proxy>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, with this configuration, I get the following error: "You don't
have permission to access http://www.cnn.com/ on this server".

The problem goes away if I remove the "Require ip" from the Proxy above.
How do I restrict the access of the Forward Proxy to a set of allowable
ip's?

Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was binding to all IP's, while the
request was coming from 127.0.0.1 at the browser. Changing
to below fixed the issue for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ProxyRequests On
        Proxyvia On
        <Proxy "*">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from 172.20.160.168       # Localhost
                Allow from 192.168.122.64       # VM debianwheezy-8.3.0
        </Proxy>
```